# get selected one value of dataview by default in ext.net

Tags: selecteditem, dataview, ext.net, onload-event

I am working with Ext.Net 1.5. and I am working with Ext:dataview.
I want to get selected one value of dataview by default. 
suggest me how is it possible??

please look at Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add following JS code:

```
if ({your_dataview_id}.store.data.length > 0) {
    {your_dataview_id}.select(0); // Selects first element in a dataview
}
```

on a client side when you want to select the first element in the dataview. Just replace {your_dataview_id} with your dataview's id

Comment: but I want to select item by its Id not by recorditem index. means blue.gif id is 1 and its recorditem index is 0.. so i want to pass Id to get selected Item

Comment: I want things like following link [link]http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?19108-Get-the-row-index-of-a-gridpanel-when-clicking-on-a-rowcommand [link]

Comment: As per the client-side docs for the DataView .select() function, you can also pass the 'id' of a record, or a Record, or the index of a Record, or just about anything else. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.DataView-method-select. When you tried passing the 'id' of the record, did it work?

Comment: I am passing **themeDataview.select(record.data.FK_themeId)**. and value of record.data.FK_themeId is 2 it means it will select gray.gif but it will selecting slat.gif.. It means it will consider 2 as rowindex.

Comment: Check 'record.data.FK_themeId' is record which you need to select? Your code looks strange.
For example: 1)Go to http://examples1.ext.net/Examples/DataView/Basic/Overview/ . 2) Open FireBug console and enter this : 
ImageView.select(ImageView.store.data.get('kids_hug.jpg')). This code selects third image in the ImageView